# Android - When to call method of Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` which has `Toolbars`. When I move to `Fragment` A, the `Toolbar` needs to be changed specifically for `Fragment` A.

`Fragment` A contains 4 other `Fragments` as A is a `FragmentPager`.

I called the method of the `Activity` like :

```
((NewsfeedActivity)getActivity()).changeTitleBesideIcon("Purchases");
        ((NewsfeedActivity)getActivity()).changeIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.purchase));
        ((NewsfeedActivity)getActivity()).changeBackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.purpleC));
        ((NewsfeedActivity)getActivity()).hideToolbarBottomMarketplace();
```

Somehow, the icon doesn't get changed, BUT the title does, along with the color.. I even set the method to `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` on the icon..

Is there a specific state where that kind of method needs to be called? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Update

This is my `changeIcon` method

```
public void changeIcon(Drawable imageDrawable){
    toolbarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    toolbarIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    toolbarIcon.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
}
```

toolbarImage is an `ImageView` located in the `Toolbar`

This is how it is :

```
<Toolbar>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView> //Toolbar Image
        <ImageView>// Toolbar Icon
    </RelativeLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

And I'm calling the methods in the `onCreateView()`..

Comment: Never heard about such methods of [`Activity`]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html: changeIcon, changeBackground... Are you sure about your code?

Comment: Use the onAttach method of the Fragment

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen It's because those methods are developer created for custom use.. In this case, I was the one who created it lol, is there any better solution on changing any properties on `Activity` from `Fragment`? @cricket, will do it now

Comment: Do you use `Toolbar` or default `ActionBar`? At least, you should also post the code for the relevant methods, e.g. `changeIcon(...)`

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to put it up, there you go :D

Comment: Hey, the snippet does not provide enough information. It is uclear about `toolbarImage` and `toolbarIcon` and I think the question content and its title also have little connection. :|

Comment: try calling it from `onCreateView` meethod..

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen I've added some more detail, and yes! Damn I forgot about saying where I put the method..

Comment: Hi. Even though you CAN do it like this, it is not the best way. Rather have a callback in your fragment which your activity needs to implement and call methods like that.

Answer (score 1):

try it.

```
public void changeIconToolbar(int resId){
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(resId);
}
```

it work for me

Comment: I am using `Drawable` to set it up and don't want to use the `.setHomeAsUpIndicator()` as it is used to pop backstack.. This solution you provided is good for those who doesn't use `.setHomeAsUpIndicator()`, but I need it..

Answer (score 0):

Well, now I can see that you possibly use `Toolbar` (rather than `ActionBar`) and once again I assume that the `Toolbar` is the [toolbar](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) added in API level 21 rather than [AppCompat Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html).

In order to use this `toolbar`, I assume that you have called `setActionBar (toolbar)` to replace the `ActionBar` with the toolbar from your layout.

NOTE: Without calling this `setActionBar (toolbar)`, your activity will continue using the default `ActionBar` (in `onCreate()`) and **nothing** will be shown.

Now, when the toolbar is in its place. I think your code will work.

PS: I recommend to use AppCompat Toolbar